# Server Log Collection SAAS

Tags: monitoring

I've looked through many SAAS for server/application monitoring. However I'm wondering if there is SAAS that just opens up a API where my application can call to submit logs, and allow me to customize alerts based on the log collected.

Eg. my application submits to http://www.saas.com/add_log
with {...,"level":"severe"}

And allows me to customize which users to alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... a little more research could have helped, but I use [Logentries](https://logentries.com).

And yes, there's an API for various functions...